# delphi XE3: how to send/get JSON data, jquery like?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3

I am a jquery developer.
I see Delphi has some libraries like SuperObject for JSON parsing.

My question is : what would be the closest way (the quickest) to send/GET JSON like in Jquery AJAX ($.getJson, $.get, $.post) ?

I need my application to communicate with a webserver (sending and getting some objects)

Regards

Comment: As on every system with a http client

Comment: ...for instance the `TIdHTTP` one, which is a part of the Indy project that is shipped with Delphi for quite a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating two separate topics. The first is how to transfer data on the Web, and the second is how to deal with the data once you have them.

To send and receive network commands, you can try one of the several free libraries available, like [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.EN.aspx), [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html), or [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/start).

Once you have your data, you can process it however you like. If you have JSON-formatted data, then you can use SuperObject or any other JSON library. If you fetched XML, then you can use an XML library. Similarly for any other kind of data you might load.

The networking libraries and the data-processing libraries tend to be separate things in the Delphi ecosystem.